# Failing sometimes for unknown reason

Tags: expression-choice, computing

*Context:* I have an automated test that sometimes fails for unknown reason. It's a sort of false positive: the feature it tests is not broken. Most of the time, either it succeeds or fails for right reason (the feature is broken).

How would you describe this phenomenon of doing the expected job most of the time, but failing a few times for (apparently) no reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In software engineering, we commonly call these [**flaky**](http://www.chromium.org/developers/tree-sheriffs/sheriff-details-chromium/handling-a-failing-test) tests.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from a perspective of statistics, your *null hypothesis* would be that your system has an existing error. The fun begins when you believe that test 123 detects error 123.

There is a good explanation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors, which has several phrases of various registers.

> Type I error - error of the first kind - false positive - crying wolf
>
> Type II error - error of the second kind - false negative - wolf present but failed to see

The latter set is from "The Boy Who Cried Wolf," one of *Aesop's Fables*.

You correctly applied the term *false positive*, which means: although the test says there's a problem, there really isn't one.

I think that if you said test 123 was occasionally "crying wolf," then even pointed-haired bosses would understand (perhaps better than "Type I error" or "false positive").

From a system integration point of view, it would be best to fix the test so that it reliably detects the problem.

Comment: +1 for literature and pointy-haired bosses and being correct, because a +2-3 isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like "the test is breaking intermittently".  It's hard to express this idea concisely though because, given the nature of testing, describing a test as "breaking" will often carry the connotation that what it is testing has failed, rather than the test itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe the false positives as an *anomaly* - an irregular, unexpected event.